# Cannot call method getFrameFromSeconds() more than one time on $media object Laravel

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg-php

I'm trying to set up a video platform for myself and for this I would like to make a timelapse from frames I'm taking from the uploaded video. This worked as long as I only took one frame from the video. The moment I tried to take more than one I got the error message:

```
Call to undefined method FFMpeg\Media\Frame::frame()
```

The library I'm using is this one: [laravel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg)

In my video controller (@store) I'm using a for loop to open the already saved video over and over until I have enough frames to make the timelapse out of it.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $durationInSeconds; $i+=5){
            $media = FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')
                ->open($videoNameToStore)
                ->getFrameFromSeconds($i)
                ->export()
                ->toDisk('thumbnails')
                ->save($i.$thumbnailNameToStore);
}
```

The thing is now that it only works in the first iteration. On the second it stops with the above mentioned error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Stack Trace:

```
ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Drivers\PHPFFMpeg::frame
vendor/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/src/Drivers/PHPFFMpeg.php:113

        $this->mediaCollection = $mediaCollection;

        $localPaths = $mediaCollection->getLocalPaths();

        if (count($localPaths) === 1 && !$this->forceAdvanced) {

            $this->media = $this->ffmpeg->open(Arr::first($localPaths));

        } else {

            $this->media = $this->ffmpeg->openAdvanced($localPaths);

        }

        return $this;

    }

    public function frame(TimeCode $timecode)

    {

        $this->media = $this->media->frame($timecode); //-> error happens here

        return $this;

    }

    public function concatWithoutTranscoding()

    {

        $localPaths = $this->mediaCollection->getLocalPaths();

        $this->media = $this->ffmpeg->open(Arr::first($localPaths))

            ->concat($localPaths);

        return $this;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like there is more than one `FFMpeg` class, which one are you using (full namespace)?

Comment: I'm using this one: 
use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;